# No such module error

Tags: ios, frameworks, watchos-2

Hello fellow stackers I know this question has been asked before but all of the answers I have seen have not worked for me. I keep getting the following error: No such module 'CloudKit'. I only get this error for the watchkit extension interfaceController the iOS project has zero issues and this whole problem started happening when watchOS 2 came out.

Things I have tried:

- changing the framework path to $(SRCROOT)
- changing the framework path to ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/CloudKit.framework
- I tried placing the CloudKit.framework file directly into my project folder which actually gets rid of the no such module error but then I get the “_OBJC_CLASS_$_viewsampleViewController” error

Please help me. Any suggestions would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently WatchOS 2 decided to drop CloudKit technologies which is a big downer. Now if you wanted to use CloudKit for the watch, you need to relay the data from the parent app which is also a huge buzz kill. I found this in the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/index.html